# custom Expendable List view child

Tags: android, layout, expandablelistview

I have a problem ,I have an expendable list view and the child row is a custom row which contains textViews and Button and a LinearLayout which I want to add a EditText view  programaticly when I click on the button in the child view ..

I have no problem at this part ,I can add the view when I click on the button ,but my problem is that when I move to another activity from Actionbar tabs the EditText views that I added gone and I couldn't see it again even if I write on it ,and i need to be visible all the time

Can any one tell me what is this problem  and any way to solve it ASAP ..Please

Thank you,

```
 @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                    boolean isLastChild, View convertView,    ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                final View rowview    =super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);


                 final EditText item_count=(EditText)rowview.findViewById(R.id.txt_count);

                Cursor child=getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);

                item_count.setText(String.valueOf(child.getInt(child.getColumnIndex("quantity"))));
            //    EditText comment=(EditText)rowview.findViewById(R.id.iman);
                //  comment.setText("Add your comment here ");



                ImageButton btn_add_count=(ImageButton)rowview.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_item);
                btn_add_count.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        count=Integer.valueOf(item_count.getText().toString());
                        count=count+1;

                        item_count.setText(String.valueOf( count));
                    }
                });
//this is the button which i click to add the views 
Button btn_add_comment=(Button)rowview.findViewById(R.id.btb_add_comment);
                btn_add_comment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                        commentLayout=(LinearLayout)rowview.findViewById(R.id.comment_layout);
                        final LinearLayout rowLayout=new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                        //
                        Button remove=new Button(getActivity());
                        remove.setText("remove");
                        remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //  int index=rowLayout.getId();
                                commentLayout.removeView(rowLayout); 
                             //rowLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Log.i("remove", "this is remove comment");
                            }
                        });
                        rowLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                        EditText comment_text=new EditText(getActivity());
                        comment_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        comment_text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        comment_text.setWidth(400);
                        comment_text.setHeight(40);

                        rowLayout.addView(remove);
                        rowLayout.addView(comment_text);

                        commentLayout.addView(rowLayout);



                    }
                });


                return rowview;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you don't save info about added rows that the activity needs to recreate the new state. Use either homegrown data storage or savedInstanceState.

Comment: how can i save the added view in savedInstanceState ,could you provide me with a sample code ,please..Thank you

Comment: you don't save your views but the data that the (new) views display. Its a model-view-controller pattern, dont forget this! Google the savedInstanceState stuff, but i myself write directly into a database, since the savedInstanceState mechanism is weird...